# Online model training in R, without a static data

Tags: r, regression, machine-learning

Let's say I have a model in R, a regression tree created by `glm`,using the `data1` dataframe:

```
Model1 = glm(DepVar ~ . ,data=data1,family="binomial")
```

Is there a way to train the model with additional new data that will be coming, say `data2` , without having data1 ?In other words, is there a way to create a new model `Model2` that is based only on `Model1` and `data2`, without keeping `data1`?

Comment: I wouldn't call a GLM a "regression tree". It's not possible to "update" a GLM with additional data like this.

Comment: I see, in general is there a model that I can use in R while I don't have to keep the initial data when I get some more new data and update the existing model?

Comment: While this is probably more of a SO or DS question, it is a good question. Online model training is very prevalent and of huge value for many use cases, such as recommender systems using Big Data. Did you ever find an answer?